# String to time in php

Tags: php, dropbox, string-to-datetime

I am making a web application that connects to user's Dropbox account. When i retrieve metadata of files and folders, Dropbox returns corresponding modified dates on following format:

"Sat, 21 Aug 2010 22:31:20 +0000"

How can i convert this to following format?

21/08/2010 22:31

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many questions on formatting dates, you should find what you are looking for by searching.

Here a quicky:

```
echo date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime($sOriginalformat));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function `strtotime()`. Have a look at the [Manual](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
strtotime("Sat, 21 Aug 2010 22:31:20 +0000");
```

Comment: Thanks. But that was what I was doing. But I was getting 1306315565 as a result.

Doesnt make any sense to me.

Comment: @Prashant That's a UNIX timestamp. `strtotime` converts the time into an integer that represents the time.  `date` can then interpret this value and format it as you wish.

Comment: date("d/m/Y H:i",strtotime("Sat, 21 Aug 2010 22:31:20 +0000"));

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtotime`. If you might ever want to do more complex things, have a look at the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) class.  It is powerful and intuitive -- I think it's more transparent than mucking around with the timestamp yourself.

```
$dt = new DateTime($sOriginalFormat);
$sNewFormat = $dt->format("d/m/Y H:i");
```

Comment: precisely what i wanted:) Thanks a lot.